# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'async' when index.js file called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, asynchronous

I have a node.js app running locally in netbeans. Its entry point is an app.js file:

```
"use strict";
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    function adopt(value) { return value instanceof P ? value : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(value); }); }
    return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
        function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : adopt(result.value).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
        step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
    });
};
var __generator = (this && this.__generator) || function (thisArg, body) {
    var _ = { label: 0, sent: function() { if (t[0] & 1) throw t[1]; return t[1]; }, trys: [], ops: [] }, f, y, t, g;
    return g = { next: verb(0), "throw": verb(1), "return": verb(2) }, typeof Symbol === "function" && (g[Symbol.iterator] = function() { return this; }), g;
    function verb(n) { return function (v) { return step([n, v]); }; }
    function step(op) {
        if (f) throw new TypeError("Generator is already executing.");
        while (g && (g = 0, op[0] && (_ = 0)), _) try {
            if (f = 1, y && (t = op[0] & 2 ? y["return"] : op[0] ? y["throw"] || ((t = y["return"]) && t.call(y), 0) : y.next) && !(t = t.call(y, op[1])).done) return t;
            if (y = 0, t) op = [op[0] & 2, t.value];
            switch (op[0]) {
                case 0: case 1: t = op; break;
                case 4: _.label++; return { value: op[1], done: false };
                case 5: _.label++; y = op[1]; op = [0]; continue;
                case 7: op = _.ops.pop(); _.trys.pop(); continue;
                default:
                    if (!(t = _.trys, t = t.length > 0 && t[t.length - 1]) && (op[0] === 6 || op[0] === 2)) { _ = 0; continue; }
                    if (op[0] === 3 && (!t || (op[1] > t[0] && op[1] < t[3]))) { _.label = op[1]; break; }
                    if (op[0] === 6 && _.label < t[1]) { _.label = t[1]; t = op; break; }
                    if (t && _.label < t[2]) { _.label = t[2]; _.ops.push(op); break; }
                    if (t[2]) _.ops.pop();
                    _.trys.pop(); continue;
            }
            op = body.call(thisArg, _);
        } catch (e) { op = [6, e]; y = 0; } finally { f = t = 0; }
        if (op[0] & 5) throw op[1]; return { value: op[0] ? op[1] : void 0, done: true };
    }
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
import * as express_1 from "express";
import * as cors_1 from "cors";
import * as logger_1 from "./config/logger.js";
import * as database_1 from"./database/index.js";
import * as auth_routes_1 from "./routes/auth.routes.js";
import * as auth_routes_2 from "./routes/items.routes.js";
// import cron from 'node-cron'
import * as index_1 from "./helper/scrapping/index.js";
import * as morgan_1 from "morgan";
var scrap = new index_1.Scrapping();
var app = (0, express_1.default)();
(0, database_1.default)();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
app.use((0, cors_1.default)());
app.use(express_1.default.json({
    limit: "50mb",
    type: [
        "application/json",
        "text/plain", // AWS sends this content-type for its messages/notifications
    ],
}));
app.use(express_1.default.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use((0, morgan_1.default)(':date *** :method :: :url ** :response-time'));
app.use(routes_1.default);
setInterval(function () { return __awaiter(void 0, void 0, void 0, function () {
    return __generator(this, function (_a) {
        switch (_a.label) {
            case 0:
                console.log('running jobs');
                return [4 /*yield*/, scrap.saveDailyJobSimilarItem()];
            case 1:
                _a.sent();
                return [4 /*yield*/, scrap.saveDailyJobSameItem()];
            case 2:
                _a.sent();
                console.log('cleaning');
                return [4 /*yield*/, scrap.cleanDailyJobsCategories()];
            case 3:
                _a.sent();
                return [4 /*yield*/, scrap.cleanDailyJobsItems()];
            case 4:
                _a.sent();
                return [2 /*return*/];
        }
    });
}); }, 86400000);
// setInterval(async () => {
//   await scrap.saveDailyJobSameItem()
//   console.log('running same job')
// }, 92500000)
// setTimeout(async () => {
//   console.log('it begins')
//   await scrap.saveDailyJobSimilarItem()
//   console.log('running similar job')
// }, 1000)
// setTimeout(async () => {
// console.log('it begins 2.0')
//   await scrap.saveDailyJobSameItem()
//   console.log('running same job')
// }, 3600000)
app.get('/test-simi', function (req, res) { return __awaiter(void 0, void 0, void 0, function () {
    return __generator(this, function (_a) {
        switch (_a.label) {
            case 0: 
            // const x = await scrap.saveDailyJobSameItem()
            return [4 /*yield*/, scrap.saveDailyJobSimilarItem()];
            case 1:
                // const x = await scrap.saveDailyJobSameItem()
                _a.sent();
                res.json('running');
                return [2 /*return*/];
        }
    });
}); });
app.get('/test-same', function (req, res) { return __awaiter(void 0, void 0, void 0, function () {
    return __generator(this, function (_a) {
        switch (_a.label) {
            case 0: return [4 /*yield*/, scrap.saveDailyJobSameItem()
                // const x = await scrap.saveDailyJobSimilarItem()
            ];
            case 1:
                _a.sent();
                // const x = await scrap.saveDailyJobSimilarItem()
                res.json('running');
                return [2 /*return*/];
        }
    });
}); });
app.listen(port, function () {
    logger_1.logger.info("server listening on http://localhost:".concat(port));
});
```

That app.js invokes an index.js file shown here:

```
// /* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function */
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";
import Model from "../../schema/scrapped-items.model";
import _ from "underscore";
import dailyJob from "../../schema/daily-job.model";
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import CategoryModel from "../../schema/category.model";
import itemModel from "../../schema/item.model";
import { similarity } from "../utils/similarity";
import dailyJobModel from "../../schema/daily-job.model";
import categoryModel from "../../schema/category.model";
import { logger } from '../../config/logger';

class Scrapping {
public async scrapCall(item) {
    try {
      const url = `https://xxx-yyy.zzz.com/api/v1/scrap-item?item=${item}`;
      const response = await axios.get(url);
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
  public async ebayScrapping(item) {
    try {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ["--no-sandbox"] });
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto("https://www.ebay.com/");
      await page.waitForSelector("#gh-ac");
      await page.type("#gh-ac", `${item}`);
      await page.click('input[value="Search"]');

      await page.waitForSelector("div.s-item__wrapper");

      const link = await page.$$eval("img.s-item__image-img", (items) => {
        return items.map((item: any) => {
          return item.src;
        });
      });

      const title = await page.$$eval("h3.s-item__title", (items) => {
        return items.map((item: any) => {
          return item.innerText;
        });
      });

      const price = await page.$$eval("span.s-item__price", (items) => {
        return items.map((item: any) => {
          return item.innerText;
        });
      });

      const invs = [];

      for (let i = 0, length = 17; i < length; i++) {
        const inv: any = {
          price: this.priceToStr(price[i]),
          title: title[i],
        };
        if (i < link.length) {
          inv.link = link[i];
          inv.baseCurrency = "$";
          inv.date = new Date();
        }
        invs.push(inv);
      }

      return invs;
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof puppeteer.errors.TimeoutError) {
        return error.message;
      }
    }
  }
  public async ebayScrappingDaily(
    itemId?: any,
    user?: any,
    id?: any,
    item?: any
  ) {
    try {

      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ["--no-sandbox"] });
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto("https://www.ebay.com/");
      await page.waitForSelector("#gh-ac");
      await page.type("#gh-ac", `${item}`);
      await page.click('input[value="Search"]');

      await page.waitForSelector("div.s-item__wrapper");

      const link = await page.$$eval("img.s-item__image-img", (items) => {
        return items.map((item: any) => {
          return item.src;
        });
      });

      const title = await page.$$eval("h3.s-item__title", (items) => {
        return items.map((item: any) => {
          return item.innerText;
        });
      });

      const price = await page.$$eval("span.s-item__price", (items) => {
        return items.map((item: any) => {
          return item.innerText;
        });
      });

      const invs = [];

      for (let i = 0, length = 17; i < length; i++) {
        const inv: any = {
          price: this.priceToStr(price[i]),
          title: title[i],
        };
        if (i < link.length) {
          inv.link = link[i];
          inv.baseCurrency = "$";
          inv.date = new Date();
        }
        invs.push(inv);
      }

      return invs;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw new Error(error.message);
    }
  }
  public async saveScrapItem(category, item_title, itemId, user) {

    const same_data = await this.scrappingBee(item_title, itemId);
    same_data.forEach(x => x.similarity = similarity(x.title,item_title))

    let good_items = []
    for(const aitem of same_data){
      if(aitem.similarity >= 0.8) good_items.push(aitem)
    }
    if(good_items.length == 0){
      good_items = same_data.slice(0,30)
    }
    const similar_data = same_data.slice(good_items.length,same_data.length)

    const average = await this.getAveragePrice(good_items);
    const median = await this.getMedianPrice(good_items);
    const {high, low} = await this.getHighLowPrice(same_data)

    const createNewScrapItem = await Model.create({
      _itemId: itemId,
      _userId: user,
      similar_data: similar_data,
      same_data: same_data,
      average,
      median,
      highest_price: high,
      lowest_price: low,
    });

    if (createNewScrapItem) return true;
  }
  public async saveDailyJobSimilarItem() {

    // const data = await Model.find({});

    // const similar_data = data.map((item) => item.similar_data).flat()
    const categories = await CategoryModel.find({});

    const all_categories = categories[0].category


    const items = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < all_categories.length; i += 1) {
      items.push(all_categories.slice(i, i + 1));
    }
    let response;
    let offset = 0;

    _(items).each((item) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        item.forEach(async (category) => {
          if (category) {
            // console.log(item.title)
            const data = await this.scrappingBeeDaily(category);

            // data.forEach(el => el.similarity = similarity(el.title,item.title))

            const average = await this.getAveragePrice(data);

            const median = await this.getMedianPrice(data);

            return await dailyJob.create({
              median: median,
              average: average,
              category: category,
              similar_data: data,
            });
          }
          return response;
        });
      }, 25000 + offset);
      offset += 25000;
    });
  }
  public async saveDailyJobSameItem() {

    const items_data = await itemModel.find({});
    const same_data = items_data.map((item) => {
      let item_keywords = item.item_keywords.filter(x=>x.toLowerCase() != item.item_title.toLowerCase())
      let title = item.item_title
      item_keywords.forEach(x=>title+=" "+x)
      return {
        title: title,
        item: item._id,
      }
    })


    const items = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < same_data.length; i += 1) {
      items.push(same_data.slice(i, i + 1));
    }
    let response;
    let offset = 0;

    _(items).each((item) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        item.forEach(async (item) => {

          if (item.title !== 'Shop on eBay') {
            // console.log(item.title)
            const data = await this.scrappingBeeDaily(item.title, item.item);

            data.forEach(el => el.similarity = similarity(el.title,item.title))

            let same_data = data
            let good_items = []
            for(const aitem of same_data){
              if(aitem.similarity >= 0.8) good_items.push(aitem)
            }
            if(good_items.length == 0){
              good_items = same_data.slice(0,30)
            }

            const average = await this.getAveragePrice(good_items);

            const median = await this.getMedianPrice(good_items);

            const {high, low} = await this.getHighLowPrice(good_items)
             

            return await dailyJob.create({
              _scrapId: item.item,
              median: median,
              average: average,
              same_data: data,
              lowest_price: low,
              highest_price: high,
            });
          }
          return response;
        });
      }, 25000 + offset);
      offset += 25000;
    });
  }


              },
            },
          },
        },
      });

      const response = data.data;

      const invs = [];

      await response.map(async (item) => {
        if (item) {
          const inv: any = {
            price: await this.priceToStr(item.price),
            title: item.title,
          };
          if (item.link) {
            inv.link = item.link;
            inv.baseCurrency = "$";
            inv.date = new Date();
            inv.url = item.url
            inv.item = id
          }
          invs.push(inv);
        }
      });
      return invs.slice(0,100);
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error("ScrapingBee Error: " + error.message);
    }
  }
  public async scrappingBeeDaily(items, id = null) {
    const url = items.split(" ").join("+")
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get("https://app.scrapingbee.com/api/v1", {
        params: {
          api_key:
            "DCXO8PT2BDINHZNQDJUMHLK9FYAKG3MDW9U4T1A4G7KNZ4IN7WNYA796GELUFA1KW9VQ7R9ZXSXN28IH",
          url: `https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313&_nkw=${url}&_sacat=0`,
          // Wait for there to be at least one
          // non-empty .event-tile element
          wait_for: ".s-item",
          extract_rules: {
            data: {
              // Lets create a list with data
              // extracted from the .event-tile element
              selector: ".s-item",
              type: "list",
              // Each object in the list should
              output: {
                // have a title lifted from
                // the .event-tile__title element
                price: ".s-item__price",
                title: ".s-item__title",
                link: {
                  selector: ".s-item__image-wrapper img",
                  output: "@src",
                },
                url: {
                  selector: ".s-item__link",
                  output: "@href"
                }
              },
            },
          },
        },
      });

      const response = data.data;
      const invs = [];

      await response.map(async (item) => {
        if (item) {
          const inv: any = {
            price: await this.priceToStr(item.price),
            title: item.title,
          };
          if (item.link) {
            inv.link = item.link;
            inv.baseCurrency = "$";
            inv.date = new Date();
            inv.url = item.url
            inv.category = items
            inv.item = id
          }
          invs.push(inv);
        }
      });
      return invs.slice(0,100);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      throw new Error("ScrapingBee Error: " + error.message);
    }
  }
  public async testing(id) {
    console.log('testing...')
    let items_data = await itemModel.find({});
    console.log('asdfasdf')
    console.log(items_data.length)
    items_data = items_data.filter(x=>x._id==id)
    if(items_data.length > 1 || items_data.length ==0){
      console.log('fail asdfss')
      console.log(items_data.length)
      return
    }
    console.log('whhhhaaat')
    // console.log(items_data)
    // console.log(items_data[0])
    const same_data = items_data.map((item) => {
      let item_keywords = item.item_keywords.filter(x=>x.toLowerCase() != item.item_title.toLocaleLowerCase())
      let title = item.item_title
      item_keywords.forEach(x=>title+=" "+x)
      return {
        title: title,
        item: item._id,
      }
    })


    const items = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < same_data.length; i += 1) {
      items.push(same_data.slice(i, i + 1));
    }
    let response;
    let offset = 0;

    _(items).each((item) => {
      // setTimeout(() => {
        item.forEach(async (item) => {

          if (item.title !== 'Shop on eBay') {
            // console.log(item.title)
            const data = await this.scrappingBeeDaily(item.title, item.item);

            // console.log(data)

            data.forEach(el => el.similarity = similarity(el.title,item.title))

            const average = await this.getAveragePrice(data);

            const median = await this.getMedianPrice(data);

            const {high, low} = await this.getHighLowPrice(data)
             
console.log('creating')
            return await dailyJob.create({
              _scrapId: item.item,
              median: median,
              average: average,
              same_data: data,
              lowest_price: low,
              highest_price: high,
            });
          }
          return response;
        });
      });
      // offset += 25000;
    // });
  }
}

export { Scrapping };
```

When executed, the console log states:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\linco\Documents\NetBeansProjects\pricer_collectibles\app.js" "run" "build" "&&" "node" "./bin/www"
file:///C:/Users/linco/Documents/NetBeansProjects/pricer_collectibles/helper/scrapping/index.js:15
public async scrapCall(item) {
       ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'async'
    at ModuleLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:168:18)
    at callTranslator (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:279:14)
    at ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:285:30)

Node.js v21.7.1
Done.
```

tsconfig.json file is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "ESNEXT",                       /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "ESNext",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "lib": ["dom","ESNext"],                        /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    "allowJs": true,                          /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    "jsx": "react-native",                    /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    // "outDir": "./",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    "noEmit": true,                           /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    "isolatedModules": true,                  /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */
"types": [ "node" ],
"typeRoots": [ "../node_modules/@types" ],
    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "Node",               /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,     /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "resolveJsonModule": true                 /* Allows importing modules with a ‘.json’ extension, which is a common practice in node projects. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "./",                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "./",                       /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "babel.config.js", "metro.config.js", "jest.config.js"],
    "ts-node": {
        "esm": true,
        "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node"
    }
}
```

package.json file is:

```
{
  "name": "pricer-collectibles",
  "version": "0.0.4",
  "main": "app.js",
  "type": "module", 
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "cors": "2.8.5",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "16.4.5",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "less-middleware": "~2.2.1",
    "mongoose": "8.2.2",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "window": "4.2.7",
    "winston": "3.12.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js run build && node ./bin\/www"
  }  
}
```

Why is the environment showing an error where I'm trying to call asynchronous functions?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use Typescript syntax in a JavaScript source file. JavaScript does not use the `public` keyword.

Comment: Are you sure you included [enough](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) files in your question?